# remove hidden field from final json after submit using Formik

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, formik

I build a simple form using formik. I have a situation that one field is hidden after I choose in radio buttun 'no'.
But if I enter value to this field and then choose 'no' to hide it, and submit the form I will get in the final json also the value of the hidden field.
My expectation is when field isn't show to the screen, remove it from the final json.

My form:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

import { Radio } from "antd";

const CustomFormik = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          input1: null,
          radio: null,
          input2: null
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <>
            <Form
              onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
              className="custom-formik-container"
            >
              <Form.Group>
                <span>input1: </span>
                <Form.Control
                  id={"input1"}
                  name={"input1"}
                  {...formik.getFieldProps("input1")}
                />
              </Form.Group>

              {formik.getFieldProps("radio").value !== 2 && (
                <Form.Group>
                  <span>input2: </span>
                  <Form.Control
                    id={"input2"}
                    name={"input2"}
                    {...formik.getFieldProps("input2")}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              )}

              <Form.Group>
                <span>radio: </span>
                <Radio.Group {...formik.getFieldProps("radio")}>
                  <Radio value={1}>yes</Radio>
                  <Radio value={2}>no</Radio>
                </Radio.Group>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>

            <button
              style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 30,
                background: "#113776",
                color: "#fff"
              }}
              onClick={() => formik.handleSubmit()}
            >
              S U B M I T
            </button>
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
export default CustomFormik;
```

For example enter:
'abc' to the first input.
'efg' to the second input.
'no' to the radio button.

The final json in console.log will be:

```
{input1: "abc",input2: "efg", radio: 2}
```

But my expectation in to be:

```
{input1: "abc", radio: 2}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-euclid-9gl6ky?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits your needs but I had a similar case in my project using `redux-form` and what i did was to delete the property before submiting it

sth like this

```
    onSubmit={(values) => {
      if (values.radio === 2) {
        let clonedValues = { ...values };
        delete clonedValues.input2;

        console.log(clonedValues);
      } else {
        console.log(values);
      }
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I thought about it, but in more complex form with a lot of fields I will have a lot of condition. I also thought to reset the hidden field but this is with the same problem of multi condition. Maybe there is something build-in in formik to solve this?

Comment: i tried with `input disabled` and also with `Field disabled` but it seems that `Formik` submits these values regardless of the `disabled` state

Comment: there is also an issue as closed but i didnt see a pull request https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1376

Comment: Yes I saw this but cannot understand how really use it.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the job.

```
        onSubmit={(values) => {
      if(values.radio === 2){
        delete values['input2'];
      }
      console.log(values);
    }}
```

Comment: Thank for answer. Yes, this will do the job but when I will have a lot of fields it will be more complex and hard to manage.

Comment: You can maintain an array of objects and before form submission, you can loop and delete those fields.

Comment: You right, but think about this case:
You have something like 10 radio buttons, every button hide any field. So, in onSubmit function you have to do something like this:

if(values.radio1 === 0){
delete values['input1']
} else if(values.radio2 === 0){
delete values['input2']
}
and more and more....